# IPSec VPN between DO Droplet and other (trusted) provider

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, ipsec

I have a requirement to set up IPsec VPN between my company's droplet and a network owned by partner company that uses another provider.
Tooling:

- Debian (my droplet) with IP e.g `169.22.231.13` and local address e.g `10.22.0.50`
- IPsec-Tools & Racoon (Racoon in itself is not required - LibreSwan or StrongSwan are also acceptable, though I have a feeling that might not be the issue)
- mode = Tunnel
- ESP

I've created a test environment in order to try out the tooling and feasibility of the task, consisting of 2 Droplets that I managed to connect according to the points above, and managed to achieve what I wanted (while testing with my own droplets).

Onto the real case - here's the description of the remote server (owned by the partner company):

- entry point has a firewall (my droplet is white-listed) - e.g public IP `153.132.142.123`
- service running on my droplet needs to connect to a service behind this public IP, e.g internal IP `10.100.232.11`
- remote network has mapped my internal address in their network interface

I have managed to set up a VPN tunnel between my droplet and the remote network, according to:

- `racoonctl show-sa ipsec` showing both in and out directions of the tunnel, with `esp mode=tunnel` and `state=mature`
- `racoonctl -l show-sa isakmp` is showing correct destination and `Phase 2 = 1`, also logs are reporting that connection is successfully made

However, when I try to ping the `10.100.232.11` address, it hangs, and when partner service pings my internal IP (that I mapped in Security Association Database) they tell me this IP is unreachable. I don't see ESP packets going out.

I have following suspicions:

- my and/or partner networks are using NAT, while we both configured our VPNs with NAT Traversal = OFF;
- DigitalOcean does not allow IPsec VPNs to other providers, due to some internal networking rules to protect our droplets
  Can someone point me in the right direction? I would be most grateful to whomever could share some knowledge on this topic with me.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you strictly required to use racoon, rather than something from the current era such as strongSwan or LibreSwan?

Comment: Do you see ESP packets going out from your system, and does the other system see them coming in? Does the other system have a route for your internal address through eth0?

Comment: @grawity I'm not required to use Racoon - LibreSwan or StrongSwan are acceptable if they work (though I have a feeling that might not be the issue).
I don't see ESP packets going out.
Other system has route mapping for my internal address.
(I updated my post)